# Como indicar a una función en R que un argumento es una columna de un dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Usando la libreria ggplot2, tengo que meter en una función esto

```
ggplot(., aes(x = "", y = `xG/90`))
```

donde xG/90 es una columna de mi dataframe, pero quiero hacer una función para que me saque el gráfico, por lo que tengo que pasar `xG/90` como argumento pero al intertarlo de esta manera

```
doPlotBox <- function(df, color, title, estadistica){

df %>% 
    ggplot(., aes(x = "", y = estadistica))
```

No me deja poner eso como argumento

```
doPlotBox(del_bun, "forestgreen", "xG cada 90 minutos", `xG/90`)
```

saltandome el siguiente error :

Error in `stat_boxplot()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'xG/90' not found

Tampoco si lo pongo entre parentesis me deja

¿Cómo podría ponerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Vale,

Se pone con dos corchetes y entre comillas de la siguiente forma :

```
[["xG/90"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Una gráfico como este:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

dónde busques incorporarlo a una función y parametrizar la variable a usar, se puede escribir de está forma:

```
doPlotBox <- function(df, color, title, estadistica) {
  
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(y = {{estadistica}})) +
    geom_boxplot()
  
}
```

E invocarlo luego así: `doPlotBox(mtcars, estadistica = mpg)`, esta es la forma "natural" con las que trabajaríamos con las funciones de `ggplot` o en general de los paquetes de `tidyverse`, al menos desde el 2020  ( Ver: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/ )

nota lo siguiente:

- Con los corchetes dobles de `{{estadistica}}` le indicamos a la evaluación que hace `ggplot` que la variable que recibe no es el dato literal sino el nombre de una variable del `data.frame`
- La invocación de la función se hace, indicando la variable sin ninguna comilla